# Wifi problems after restart or suspend

Tags: release-freya, release-loki, wifi

when I restart or suspend my machine I suddenly cannot connect to my wifi network, what I read on other posts is to use this line code:

```
sudo killall NetworkManager
```

This help when I'm just using my wireless network, but when I'm with the cable the network icon change and try to find the cable network.

Comment: I guess this is hardware specific issue. It doesn't occur on my mbp. So, it would be helpful if you include your pc specs.

Answer (score 2):

I will have to investigate further to find an automatic solution, but this problem occasionally happens to me as well.

The solution I use is to run

`sudo restart NetworkManager`

This restarts network manager cleanly and re-establishes any connections you had.

There was a bug in older Ubuntu systems where this would occur and you had to add a command to one of the files uses by pm-utils, but it seems this problem is not exactly the same as the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

This seems a rather frequent problem even in Loki and ubuntu 16.04: [16.04 LTS wifi connection issues](https://askubuntu.com/q/762198/47206) and it happened very often on my system.

After following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/768268/47206) it got less frequent I guess.

What it says is:

> 1. Get details of your PCI wireless card by running `sudo lshw -class network`
> 2. Get your card model info according to the product line. For instance, as you can see in the question description it says `product:
>      RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter` so the model of my card is
>      `RTL8723BE`
> 3. Open or create `/etc/pm/config.d/config` and add `SUSPEND_MODULES="rtl8723be"`(replace rtl8723be with your own model
>      number) Then run `echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=N" | sudo tee
>      /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf` and reboot.

It rarely happens now and when it does I use the command `service network-manager restart`.

That can be associated with a shortcut key. I prefer a desktop launcher to run from Slingshot:

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/restart_wifi.desktop
```

with:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Icon=urserver
Name=Restart Wifi
Type=Application
Exec=bash -c 'service network-manager restart'
Categories=Network;
```