# Wifi down after waking up from a long suspend

Tags: wifi

All,

Here is some background info

My Chip : Intel 7265 wireless chip.

My OS: eOS loki

My kernel: 4.8.0-39-generic x86_64

My wifi will down after waking up from a long suspend. Within network manager, all the wireless networks are gone. I cannot signin to any wireless network.

The dmesg output goes here. Can someone help me on this?
[image]

lshw -C network output goes here

[image]

Comment: this is a frequent occurrence in ubuntu - http://askubuntu.com/questions/762198/16-04-lts-wifi-connection-issues. I did  this: http://askubuntu.com/a/768268/47206, which makes the occurrence less frequent I think. But when it happens I do `service network-manager restart` (which can be put in a desktop file or associated with a shortcut )

Comment: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/1382/170,

Comment: What does `rfkill list all` report after suspend?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wifi problems after restart or suspend](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1382/wifi-problems-after-restart-or-suspend)

Answer (score 1):

This seems a rather frequent problem in ubuntu 16.04 on which Loki is based ([askubuntu question: 16.04 LTS wifi connection issues](https://askubuntu.com/q/762198/47206)) and it happened very often on my system.

You can try other answers under that askubuntu question, but for me it got less frequent (I guess) after following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/768268/47206) .

What it says is:

> 1. Get details of your PCI wireless card by running `sudo lshw -class network`
> 2. Get your card model info according to the product line. For instance, as you can see in the question description it says `product:
>      RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter` so the model of my card is
>      `RTL8723BE`
> 3. Open or create `/etc/pm/config.d/config` and add `SUSPEND_MODULES="rtl8723be"`(replace rtl8723be with your own model
>      number) Then run `echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=N" | sudo tee
>      /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf` and reboot.

It rarely happens now and when it does I use the command `service network-manager restart`.

That can be associated with a shortcut key. I prefer a desktop launcher to run from Slingshot:

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/restart_wifi.desktop
```

with:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Icon=urserver
Name=Restart Wifi
Type=Application
Exec=bash -c 'service network-manager restart'
Categories=Network;
```