# Can't activate wireless from WingPanel

Tags: wingpanel, wifi, networking

I am facing a problem in that after turning off wireless I can not reactivate from the wingpanel! When I click on the wireless switch in the network nothing happens and I have to enter network settings to be able to reactivate and this is annoying. Need help
Thank you

Comment: i'm facing the same problem. A fix would be really nice.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

That's a [known bug](https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel-indicator-network/issues/16) .

There's even a possible solution in there, but sadly nobody from the elementary team decided to fix it...

Comment: Thanks for the info! Can you share the possible solution? This is annoying

Comment: See if it helps: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/1382/6398

Comment: Confirmed still a problem  in 2019 version 5.1 .  My friends computer has this bug.  My computer does not.